# Is there a way to find out the line in JavaScript that changed an HTML property?

Tags: javascript, html, firebug

There is a specific line of code in my functions.js file which adds `height: 371px` to a `<div>` in the HTML output and I really need to remove that.

My question is: Is there a smart way to find out which exact line in my JavaScript file adds this property?

I've been searching for `371px`, but this numerical value changes as soon as I resize my browser window. I've also been searching for `height` and got more than 200 entries, so I gave up.

I'm using Firebug by the way, but not very familiar with it.

Comment: In that case your code must be triggered by resize function, in jQuery for example thats $(window).on('resize' ...

Comment: Hmm, search results for "resize" = zero

Comment: Do you have your code anywhere available online ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to add an HTML breakpoint on that `<div>`. To do so right-click the element inside the [*HTML* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel) and choose *Break On Attribute Change*.

The next time you resize the window the script execution should stop exactly at the line where the height is set.